# App Crashes in the Background Because of CPU Usage

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, core-location

I have a workout tracking app written in SwiftUI. Without getting into details of the code since I don't even know what part of code is the problem, it is using CoreLocation to get location updates and using CoreData to save data related to location. It seems that while it's running in the foreground it's all fine but after 40 minutes - 60 minutes of running in the background it crashes. When I read the logs I see the below log. I cannot understand from the log where in my code I am supposed to look for a solution? What action am I taking in the background that is taking too much CPU capacity, is it the saving to CoreData? All UI updates are supposed to be suspended automatically since the app is in the background, right? Can you see something in the log that can give me some hint what the problem is.

I have seen this page on Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/WorkLessInTheBackground.html
the section under Resolving Runaway Background App Crashes, but I cannot see the things that are referenced there in the log. Can you? Any suggestion how I can proceed to pinpoint the problem?

```
Data Source:      Microstackshots
Shared Cache:     0x26630000 806C7B9F-DF16-345B-9D6C-B3FAB1733341

Command:          OutdoorWorkout
Path:             /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX/OutdoorWorkout.app/OutdoorWorkout
Identifier:       WorkoutBundleID
Version:          1.0 (1)
Beta Identifier:  4D39B290-3181-42D0-BC89-10E43C4A441F
PID:              21776

Event:            cpu usage
Action taken:     Process killed
CPU:              48 seconds cpu time over 59 seconds (82% cpu average), exceeding limit of 80% cpu over 60 seconds
CPU limit:        48s
Limit duration:   60s
CPU used:         48s
CPU duration:     59s
Duration:         58.76s
Duration Sampled: 53.49s
Steps:            11

Hardware model:   iPhone12,1
Active cpus:      6


Heaviest stack for the target process:
  11  ??? (libdyld.dylib + 4996) [0x1a688b384]
  11  ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 138608) [0x100795d70]
  11  ??? (UIKitCore + 10938180) [0x1aabc1744]
  11  ??? (GraphicsServices + 13772) [0x1b0df05cc]
  11  ??? (CoreFoundation + 682952) [0x1a6a0ebc8]
  11  ??? (CoreFoundation + 684764) [0x1a6a0f2dc]
  11  ??? (CoreFoundation + 683596) [0x1a6a0ee4c]
  11  ??? (CoreFoundation + 704796) [0x1a6a1411c]
  11  ??? (SwiftUI + 368820) [0x1df0a00b4]
  11  ??? (SwiftUI + 368524) [0x1df09ff8c]
  11  ??? (SwiftUI + 368668) [0x1df0a001c]
  11  ??? (SwiftUI + 1954804) [0x1df2233f4]
  11  ??? (SwiftUI + 1841768) [0x1df207a68]
  11  ??? (SwiftUI + 4643360) [0x1df4b3a20]
  11  ??? (SwiftUI + 1841824) [0x1df207aa0]
  11  ??? (SwiftUI + 1841460) [0x1df207934]
  11  ??? (SwiftUI + 1842352) [0x1df207cb0]
  11  ??? (SwiftUI + 1842940) [0x1df207efc]
  11  ??? (AttributeGraph + 37600) [0x1d324c2e0]
  11  ??? (AttributeGraph + 17276) [0x1d324737c]
  11  ??? (AttributeGraph + 16064) [0x1d3246ec0]
  9   ??? (AttributeGraph + 115316) [0x1d325f274]
  9   ??? (SwiftUI + 3002020) [0x1df322ea4]
  9   ??? (SwiftUI + 3001388) [0x1df322c2c]
  9   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 48056) [0x10077fbb8]
  9   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 48980) [0x10077ff54]
  9   ??? (SwiftUI + 3251672) [0x1df35fdd8]
  4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 50624) [0x1007805c0]
  4   ??? (SwiftUI + 4883608) [0x1df4ee498]
  4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 61856) [0x1007831a0]
  4   ??? (SwiftUI + 5396712) [0x1df56b8e8]
  4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 65172) [0x100783e94]
  4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 63348) [0x100783774]
  4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 453660) [0x1007e2c1c]
  4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 440244) [0x1007df7b4]
  4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 425960) [0x1007dbfe8]
  4   ??? (libswiftCore.dylib + 1299560) [0x1b439d468]
  4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 462292) [0x1007e4dd4]
  4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 421692) [0x1007daf3c]
  4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 428164) [0x1007dc884]
  4   ??? (libswiftCore.dylib + 1460088) [0x1b43c4778]
  4   ??? (libswiftCore.dylib + 1461172) [0x1b43c4bb4]
  4   ??? (libswiftCore.dylib + 353072) [0x1b42b6330]
  4   ??? (libswiftCore.dylib + 353312) [0x1b42b6420]
  4   ??? (libswiftCore.dylib + 2949328) [0x1b45300d0]
  4   ??? (libswiftCore.dylib + 2949284) [0x1b45300a4]
  4   ??? (libswiftCore.dylib + 1464092) [0x1b43c571c]
  2   ??? (libswiftCore.dylib + 1469228) [0x1b43c6b2c]
  1   ??? (libswiftCore.dylib + 505172) [0x1b42db554]
  1   ??? (libsystem_malloc.dylib + 45860) [0x1a6781324]


Powerstats for:   OutdoorWorkout [21776]
Bundle ID:        WorkoutBundleID
Adam ID:          0
Is first party:   No
App version:      1.0
Build version:    1
Is Beta:          No
Share with Devs:  No
UUID:             66A62427-9651-3C4E-8E72-FAAF0682DD5C
Path:             /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX/OutdoorWorkout.app/OutdoorWorkout
Architecture:     arm64
Footprint:        85.62 MB
Start time:       2020-09-06 13:50:39 -0400
End time:         2020-09-06 13:51:33 -0400
Num samples:      11 (100%)
CPU Time:         45.764s
Primary state:    11 samples Non-Frontmost App, Non-Suppressed, User mode, Effective Thread QoS Background, Requested Thread QoS User Interactive, Override Thread QoS Unspecified
User Activity:    11 samples Idle, 0 samples Active
Power Source:     11 samples on Battery, 0 samples on AC
  11  start + 3 (libdyld.dylib + 4996) [0x1a688b384]
    11  ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 138608) [0x100795d70]
      11  UIApplicationMain + 1935 (UIKitCore + 10938180) [0x1aabc1744]
        11  GSEventRunModal + 163 (GraphicsServices + 13772) [0x1b0df05cc]
          11  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 479 (CoreFoundation + 682952) [0x1a6a0ebc8]
            11  __CFRunLoopRun + 1003 (CoreFoundation + 684764) [0x1a6a0f2dc]
              11  __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 419 (CoreFoundation + 683596) [0x1a6a0ee4c]
                11  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 35 (CoreFoundation + 704796) [0x1a6a1411c]
                  11  @objc closure #1 in static NSRunLoop.addObserver + 55 (SwiftUI + 368820) [0x1df0a00b4]
                    11  closure #1 in static NSRunLoop.addObserver + 15 (SwiftUI + 368524) [0x1df09ff8c]
                      11  static NSRunLoop.flushObservers + 135 (SwiftUI + 368668) [0x1df0a001c]
                        11  thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed -> () + 27 (SwiftUI + 1954804) [0x1df2233f4]
                          11  closure #1 in ViewGraph.asyncTransaction<A> + 147 (SwiftUI + 1841768) [0x1df207a68]
                            11  ViewRendererHost.updateViewGraph<A> + 91 (SwiftUI + 4643360) [0x1df4b3a20]
                              11  closure #1 in closure #1 in ViewGraph.asyncTransaction<A> + 23 (SwiftUI + 1841824) [0x1df207aa0]
                                11  ViewGraph.flushTransactions + 187 (SwiftUI + 1841460) [0x1df207934]
                                  11  closure #1 in ViewGraph.flushTransactions + 255 (SwiftUI + 1842352) [0x1df207cb0]
                                    11  ViewGraph.runTransaction + 215 (SwiftUI + 1842940) [0x1df207efc]
                                      11  AG::Subgraph::update + 727 (AttributeGraph + 37600) [0x1d324c2e0]
                                        11  AG::Graph::update_attribute + 375 (AttributeGraph + 17276) [0x1d324737c]
                                          11  AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update + 447 (AttributeGraph + 16064) [0x1d3246ec0]
                                            9   partial apply + 39 (AttributeGraph + 115316) [0x1d325f274]
                                              9   protocol witness for static UntypedAttribute._update in conformance GeometryReader<A>.Child + 39 (SwiftUI + 3002020) [0x1df322ea4]
                                                9   GeometryReader.Child.update + 403 (SwiftUI + 3001388) [0x1df322c2c]
                                                  9   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 48056) [0x10077fbb8]
                                                    9   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 48980) [0x10077ff54]
                                                      9   VStack.init + 183 (SwiftUI + 3251672) [0x1df35fdd8]
                                                        4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 50624) [0x1007805c0]
                                                          4   HStack.init + 183 (SwiftUI + 4883608) [0x1df4ee498]
                                                            4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 61856) [0x1007831a0]
                                                              4   Group<A>.init + 91 (SwiftUI + 5396712) [0x1df56b8e8]
                                                                4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 65172) [0x100783e94]
                                                                  4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 63348) [0x100783774]
                                                                    4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 453660) [0x1007e2c1c]
                                                                      4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 440244) [0x1007df7b4]
                                                                        4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 425960) [0x1007dbfe8]
                                                                          4   Sequence.forEach + 479 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1299560) [0x1b439d468]
                                                                            4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 462292) [0x1007e4dd4]
                                                                              4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 421692) [0x1007daf3c]
                                                                                4   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 428164) [0x1007dc884]
                                                                                  4   Sequence.sorted + 255 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1460088) [0x1b43c4778]
                                                                                    4   MutableCollection<>.sort + 1027 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1461172) [0x1b43c4bb4]
                                                                                      4   protocol witness for MutableCollection._withUnsafeMutableBufferPointerIfSupported<A> in conformance ContiguousArray<A> + 27 (libswiftCore.dylib + 353072) [0x1b42b6330]
                                                                                        4   ContiguousArray.withContiguousMutableStorageIfAvailable<A> + 195 (libswiftCore.dylib + 353312) [0x1b42b6420]
                                                                                          4   partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed -> (@error @owned Error) + 27 (libswiftCore.dylib + 2949328) [0x1b45300d0]
                                                                                            4   partial apply for closure #1 in MutableCollection<>.sort + 103 (libswiftCore.dylib + 2949284) [0x1b45300a4]
                                                                                              4   UnsafeMutableBufferPointer._stableSortImpl + 703 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1464092) [0x1b43c571c]
                                                                                                2   MutableCollection<>._insertionSort + 1620 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1469228) [0x1b43c6b2c]
                                                                                                  1   protocol witness for Collection.subscript.read in conformance [A : B].Keys + 43 (libswiftCore.dylib + 505172) [0x1b42db554]
                                                                                                    1   nanov2_free_definite_size + 36 (libsystem_malloc.dylib + 45860) [0x1a6781324]
                                                                                                  1   free + 131 (libsystem_malloc.dylib + 65084) [0x1a6785e3c]
                                                                                                    1   nanov2_pointer_size + 140 (libsystem_malloc.dylib + 45028) [0x1a6780fe4]
                                                                                                1   MutableCollection<>._insertionSort + 1827 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1469436) [0x1b43c6bfc]
                                                                                                  1   _platform_memmove + 0 (libsystem_platform.dylib + 21712) [0x1a679c4d0]
                                                                                                1   MutableCollection<>._insertionSort + 1620 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1469228) [0x1b43c6b2c]
                                                        3   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 51752) [0x100780a28]
                                                          3   HStack.init + 183 (SwiftUI + 4883608) [0x1df4ee498]
                                                            3   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 77032) [0x100786ce8]
                                                              3   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 67180) [0x10078466c]
                                                                3   VStack.init + 183 (SwiftUI + 3251672) [0x1df35fdd8]
                                                                  3   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 72716) [0x100785c0c]
                                                                    3   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 68860) [0x100784cfc]
                                                                      3   Group<A>.init + 91 (SwiftUI + 5396712) [0x1df56b8e8]
                                                                        3   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 65172) [0x100783e94]
                                                                          3   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 70752) [0x100785460]
                                                                            3   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 439112) [0x1007df348]
                                                                              3   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 433956) [0x1007ddf24]
                                                                                3   Sequence.sorted + 255 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1460088) [0x1b43c4778]
                                                                                  3   MutableCollection<>.sort + 1027 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1461172) [0x1b43c4bb4]
                                                                                    3   protocol witness for MutableCollection._withUnsafeMutableBufferPointerIfSupported<A> in conformance ContiguousArray<A> + 27 (libswiftCore.dylib + 353072) [0x1b42b6330]
                                                                                      3   ContiguousArray.withContiguousMutableStorageIfAvailable<A> + 195 (libswiftCore.dylib + 353312) [0x1b42b6420]
                                                                                        3   partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed -> (@error @owned Error) + 27 (libswiftCore.dylib + 2949328) [0x1b45300d0]
                                                                                          3   partial apply for closure #1 in MutableCollection<>.sort + 103 (libswiftCore.dylib + 2949284) [0x1b45300a4]
                                                                                            3   UnsafeMutableBufferPointer._stableSortImpl + 703 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1464092) [0x1b43c571c]
                                                                                              1   MutableCollection<>._insertionSort + 1827 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1469436) [0x1b43c6bfc]
                                                                                                1   DYLD-STUB$$WebCore::BaseAudioSharedUnit::captureFailed (.cold.1) + 0 (WebCore + 30739780) [0x1b04f9d44]
                                                                                              1   MutableCollection<>._insertionSort + 1699 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1469308) [0x1b43c6b7c]
                                                                                                1   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 462612) [0x1007e4f14]
                                                                                                  1   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 424912) [0x1007dbbd0]
                                                                                                    1   swift::metadataimpl::ValueWitnesses<swift::metadataimpl::NativeBox<unsigned long long, 8ul, 8ul, 8ul> >::destroy + 0 (libswiftCore.dylib + 3235380) [0x1b4575e34]
                                                                                              1   MutableCollection<>._insertionSort + 1375 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1468984) [0x1b43c6a38]
                                                                                                1   protocol witness for Collection.subscript.read in conformance UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<A> + 67 (libswiftCore.dylib + 2479440) [0x1b44bd550]
                                                                                                  1   UnsafeMutableBufferPointer.subscript.read + 67 (libswiftCore.dylib + 2479548) [0x1b44bd5bc]
                                                                                                    1   malloc + 32 (libsystem_malloc.dylib + 65616) [0x1a6786050]
                                                        2   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 56168) [0x100781b68]
                                                          2   Group<A>.init + 91 (SwiftUI + 5396712) [0x1df56b8e8]
                                                            2   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 89672) [0x100789e48]
                                                              2   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 87744) [0x1007896c0]
                                                                2   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 430448) [0x1007dd170]
                                                                  2   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 429740) [0x1007dceac]
                                                                    2   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 425960) [0x1007dbfe8]
                                                                      2   Sequence.forEach + 479 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1299560) [0x1b439d468]
                                                                        2   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 462292) [0x1007e4dd4]
                                                                          2   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 421692) [0x1007daf3c]
                                                                            2   ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 428164) [0x1007dc884]
                                                                              2   Sequence.sorted + 255 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1460088) [0x1b43c4778]
                                                                                2   MutableCollection<>.sort + 1027 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1461172) [0x1b43c4bb4]
                                                                                  2   protocol witness for MutableCollection._withUnsafeMutableBufferPointerIfSupported<A> in conformance ContiguousArray<A> + 27 (libswiftCore.dylib + 353072) [0x1b42b6330]
                                                                                    2   ContiguousArray.withContiguousMutableStorageIfAvailable<A> + 195 (libswiftCore.dylib + 353312) [0x1b42b6420]
                                                                                      2   partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed -> (@error @owned Error) + 27 (libswiftCore.dylib + 2949328) [0x1b45300d0]
                                                                                        2   partial apply for closure #1 in MutableCollection<>.sort + 103 (libswiftCore.dylib + 2949284) [0x1b45300a4]
                                                                                          2   UnsafeMutableBufferPointer._stableSortImpl + 703 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1464092) [0x1b43c571c]
                                                                                            1   MutableCollection<>._insertionSort + 1827 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1469436) [0x1b43c6bfc]
                                                                                              1   objc_msgSend + 32 (libobjc.A.dylib + 6784) [0x1a67aaa80]
                                                                                            1   MutableCollection<>._insertionSort + 1419 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1469028) [0x1b43c6a64]
                                                                                              1   objc_msgSend + 44 (libobjc.A.dylib + 6796) [0x1a67aaa8c]
                                            1   partial apply for protocol witness for static UntypedAttribute._update in conformance DynamicLayoutViewChildGeometry + 35 (SwiftUI + 2017560) [0x1df232918]
                                              1   specialized LayoutQuery<>.update + 187 (SwiftUI + 3582596) [0x1df3b0a84]
                                                1   specialized _Layout.updateOutputAttribute<A> + 271 (SwiftUI + 3588720) [0x1df3b2270]
                                                  1   specialized static LayoutComputerDelegate.update<A> + 115 (SwiftUI + 4095736) [0x1df42def8]
                                                    1   specialized closure #1 in HVStack.updateOutput<A> + 47 (SwiftUI + 3493992) [0x1df39b068]
                                                      1   specialized closure #1 in HVStack.updateOutput<A> + 191 (SwiftUI + 3494196) [0x1df39b134]
                                                        1   closure #1 in StackLayout.Storage.update + 259 (SwiftUI + 3479700) [0x1df397894]
                                                          1   StackLayout.Header.init + 435 (SwiftUI + 3480444) [0x1df397b7c]
                                                            1   accumulateSpacing #1 in StackLayout.Header.init(layoutContext:proxies:majorAxis:minorAxisAlignment:uniformSpacing:childStorage:capacity:resizeChildrenWithTrailingOverflow:) + 315 (SwiftUI + 3482316) [0x1df3982cc]
                                                              1   LayoutTraitsProxy.spacing + 71 (SwiftUI + 929492) [0x1df128ed4]
                                                                1   LayoutComputer.EngineDelegate.spacing + 67 (SwiftUI + 4097740) [0x1df42e6cc]
                                                                  1   UnaryLayoutEngine.spacing + 79 (SwiftUI + 1704952) [0x1df1e63f8]
                                                                    1   protocol witness for UnaryLayout.spacing in conformance _PaddingLayout + 43 (SwiftUI + 4472428) [0x1df489e6c]
                                                                      1   StackLayout.Storage.spacing + 0 (SwiftUI + 3476344) [0x1df396b78]
                                            1   partial apply for specialized protocol witness for static UntypedAttribute._update in conformance UnaryLayoutComputerQuery<A> + 35 (SwiftUI + 1720128) [0x1df1e9f40]
                                              1   specialized UnaryChildGeometryQuery.update + 75 (SwiftUI + 1689492) [0x1df1e2794]
                                                1   AG::Graph::input_value_ref + 140 (AttributeGraph + 61252) [0x1d3251f44]

  Binary Images:
           0x100774000 -                ???  OutdoorWorkout              <66A62427-9651-3C4E-8E72-FAAF0682DD5C>  /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX/OutdoorWorkout.app/OutdoorWorkout
           0x1a6776000 -        0x1a6796fff  libsystem_malloc.dylib   <32E63B4B-0CB6-3798-A0D0-CEB99793BB08>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
           0x1a6797000 -        0x1a679dfff  libsystem_platform.dylib <BF25A4DA-33AF-325F-8C87-36DA4CEF0EFD>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
           0x1a67a9000 -        0x1a67dafff  libobjc.A.dylib          <B83466F5-56A4-3CA7-BDD1-3E363185282D>  /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
           0x1a688a000 -        0x1a68befff  libdyld.dylib            <9DB07277-A537-351D-AB86-5408CB5F12C3>  /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
           0x1a6968000 -        0x1a6ce4fff  CoreFoundation           <7769FFAC-4FCD-332D-A4BE-DA2F0E2FFEA5>  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
           0x1aa153000 -        0x1ab2cbfff  UIKitCore                <5AD0DCE8-0414-3CF9-97A5-13CED9C31CF7>  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
           0x1ae7a9000 -        0x1b0616fff  WebCore                  <596E181C-ABAC-3774-82DC-993327B74B46>  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
           0x1b0ded000 -        0x1b0df5fff  GraphicsServices         <1881CB29-FB7C-30D6-AB2F-F89962BB7055>  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
           0x1b4260000 -        0x1b462afff  libswiftCore.dylib       <EA3DC236-04D9-3F9B-905F-FAEA6CDB5805>  /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib
           0x1d3243000 -        0x1d327ffff  AttributeGraph           <A382CA95-E8E5-3A77-9E97-F913CE38D4CB>  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AttributeGraph.framework/AttributeGraph
           0x1df046000 -        0x1df709fff  SwiftUI                  <FC9F7A9B-A496-3884-8C9A-48957BEC5D6E>  /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
```

Comment: Would you provide your code for this?

Comment: I would be happy to but don't know which part of the code. I was hoping someone could read a bit more into the log above so that we can zero in on some part code that may be problematic.

Comment: Symbolicate `11  ??? (OutdoorWorkout + 138608) [0x100795d70` - I assume this is your part.

Comment: Thanks, let me find out why it's not symbolicated and hopefully symbolicate it and get back to you with updates. I have used one Mac and one iPhone and built it from Xcode into iPhone, so not sure why it's not already symbolicated.

Comment: @Asperi Do you know why my crash logs are not symbolicated? I have connected my iPhone to my Mac and have build the app into my device from Xcode. I thought this should automatically be symbolicated. I don't think I have changed any of the default settings. All the steps that talk about symbolicating crash reports are for builds that are submitted to the App Store.

Comment: @Dogahe Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Chathz No, unfortunately, I did not.